# Node.js WebSockets 'hiccups' and freezes

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a Node.js server using WebSockets for my game. Everything works well apart from one thing. With more players the game starts freezing. It looks as if the packets stop coming, gather up and then all are received at once.

What could be causing this and how do I stop that from happening? Any help is very much appreciated!!

EDIT: Also, it doesn't happen all the time, it's not often either. I think it only happens when players are shooting.

```
this.wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(ws.upgradeReq.headers.origin)) {
        // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
        //ws.terminate();
        console.log(new Date() + 'Connection from origin ' + ws.upgradeReq.headers.origin + ' rejected.');
        return;
    }else {
        console.log(new Date() + "New connection from " + ws._socket.remoteAddress);
        self.emit('connect', new SocketIOClient(ws));
    }
});
```

SocketIOClient:

```
WebSocketsClient.prototype.send = function(data) {
  if(this.socket.readyState == 1) {
    this.socket.send(data);
  }
};

//Inside constructor
var self = this;
this.socket.onmessage = function incoming(event) {
    self.emit('message', event.data);
}

this.socket.onerror = function () {
    self.emit('error');
    self.socket.terminate();
};

this.socket.onclose = function() {
    self.emit('disconnect');
    self.socket.terminate();
};
```

Another edit:
I have WireShark, but I don't really know how to get helpful information from it. I do have a Linux VPS which has the game running, and I can see some graphs from it. It does show maximum incoming packets (294.86 p/s) and outgoing (201.53 p/s). There are quite a few 'very steep mountains', which might be the lag spikes that the game is experiencing. The graph also shows 20-40 p/s. Here's another (day's) graph: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/edgytbtkzlzyqrs/graph.png?dl=0)

Comment: We don't know. Can you post your code please?

Comment: Any part that might be related. Anything to do with buffering. Or if it's related to the number of players then maybe there's something dodgy where a variable is shared between players. Or if it's to do with shooting, is there anything strange about the shooting code? Is the connection delayed going from the server to the client, client to server or both? Are there any parts where you use synchronous code for something that might take a long time, such as waiting for data from the network or disk or large calculations? I'm starting to suspect you're doing something slow synchronously.

Comment: Well, I think 3 players shooting at once (maybe about 4-5 bullets per second) is enough to make it 'lag'. Every shot makes the server send 4 packets to each player. Also I will add some WebSockets code to the question.

Comment: 4 packets per shot per opponent seems excessive. But that wouldn't explain why (you think) it stores up requests and then sends them all at once.

Comment: Also yes, I do have pathfinding and a physics engine in my game, which slows down the server's FPS a little bit. But could that cause it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pathfinding". The physics engine could be the problem, if it has a lot of work to do and if it's running in javascript. Do you know what I mean by "synchronous" and "asynchronous" code? Javascript isn't multi-threaded like other languages, so you have to use asynchronous code as a workaround when you need it to do lots of things at once efficiently.

Comment: Ye, I do. I use path finding to move the enemies towards players which is the performance heaviest part of the server. I use this module [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gameloop) for the game logic. Though I think there's something else causing this, since when the freeze stops, the game seems to 'speed up' on the client side.

Comment: First, verify with a network tracer tool on the server that you are getting the expected incoming network traffic from the clients and there isn't some unexpected load from them.  Second, find a way to instrument your node.js server so you can figure out if the CPU is over busy with the physics/path finding and that's what is holding up the single threaded node.js server.